# App crashes on executeFetchRequest

Tags: core-data, crash, nsfetchrequest

I don't know what happened but it suddenly crashes on the following line in the Visibility.m Entity class. I did not change anything on these classes and it used to work perfectly. Only thing is that I deleted the model by mistake. I have restored it from backup and added it again to the project.

```
vis = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];
```

This are the few lines around it

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Visibility" inManagedObjectContext:context];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"visID = %@",[tmpDict objectForKey:@"visiID"]];

NSError *error = nil;
vis = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];
```

When failing it does not show any errors in console nor any other hints. It jumps to this line in main

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

That is all...

any hints on how I could improve debugging or so? I have also tried to delete the app in the simulator but that did not workout as well.

AAH Finally I got an error message

```
Catchpoint 6 (exception thrown).2011-12-22 07:39:08.665 CaveConditions[14452:5b07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath visID not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Visibility id=9>'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3446a8bf 0x346ba1e5 0x32f6d103 0x32f6cddf 0x32f6ca39 0x32f6c0fb 0x32f6bb93 0x32f6b031 0x32f697f5 0x6b13 0x62a1 0x107d1 0x4293 0x343c9803 0x53b99 0x541b1 0x343c922b 0x4df85 0x35dc0a91 0x35e545a1 0x33210c1d 0x33210ad8)
terminate called throwing an exception[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
```

But the keypath is there... I think there is some corruption... how can I solve this?

Comment: What messages do you get in the console when the app crashes?

Comment: absolutely nothing. I added an exception handler and it will stop at the line stated above. That is all I have.

Comment: The property may be declared in the `Visibility` class but are you sure the attribute `visID` is present in your model's entity?

Comment: Hi that was it. Looks like I restored an older version where this field was not there... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

visID was missing in my model. Looks like I took an older version from backup